# Simple Custom Global Variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, global-variables

I need to run a scheduled job every few hours to refresh my API token for a 3rd party source. I want to store that API token in a global variable so I can access it from my controller. (I'm building a SPA within a single Visualforce page so there's only one controller that will be using it).

Is there a standard place where I can store this API token so I can dynamically make the headers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Custom Setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) to store this type of data. A simple hierarchy custom setting would allow to store the token easily and retrieve it on-demand in any of your Apex Code, or even by way of the  [$Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_setup.htm) global variable (e.g. if you wanted to call your API in JavaScript).

Comment: I started implementing this method until I realized my token is way too long for a custom setting. Are there any other solutions that would achieve this?

Comment: @qarthandso That's a pretty big token. You could also take a peek at [Custom Metadata](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/custom_metadata_types), but they have similar limitations. You could also probably store the data in a Document, File, or Static Resource. Those are more or less accessible, and allow more storage. If that's still not practical, you'll have to go with [Platform Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_cache_namespace_overview.htm), which may have extra costs associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [Named Credentials](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm). Thier application sounds almost exactly like your use case, but a lot simpler and more secure. ANY User can read data from Custom Settings and then potentially misuse API Access.

[image]

Comment: on quick look of this in setup, it doesn't seem it supports custom headers, and on top of that I would need dynamically changing headers. I don't think this quite solves the issue at hand. I probably should have stated that constantly updating API token has to go into the request header.

Comment: There are some settings related to using Merge Fields in the Header and Body.  This seems to suggest that one can get at least a little bit creative with Apex.  Full disclosure: The success I've enjoyed using Named Credentials is limited to a very simple application of HTTP Basic authentication. I haven't used OAuth2.0 successfully, nor have I done anything with Merge Fields in the Header or Body.

Comment: Also how do you even use it to store a token instead of a password? Just abuse on of the existing fields?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Named Credentials can store an OAuth2.0 refresh token by design, but the OP's use case sounds a little bit different... I guess you could argue that this doesn't really answer the question.  I'm thinking that using Named Credentials for this solution involves a login with every API call, rather than storing and programmatically refeshing an API token. Instead of answering the question, I supposed that I might have suggested an alternate solution.